# Select from DMP file

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to make a select froam a DMP file using TOAD for ORACLE?

In the documentation, I found this:

```
 CREATE TABLE emp_xt
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
 TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY test_dir
 LOCATION ('emp_xt.dmp')
)
 AS SELECT * FROM emp;
```

And I read something about:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'C:\';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY test_dir TO exporter;
```

Thanks.

Comment: So have you tried those things (without the `as select` if the dump file already exists)? What problem or error are you getting? How was the file exported - original export or datapump?

Comment: @Alex Poole I dont know exactly how to write this query. The error im getting is: [Error] Execution (5: 24): ORA-06564: o objeto TEST_DIR não existe.

Comment: You've shown the `create directory` command too. Have you run that, with a suitable OS directory path, before trying to createthe externaltable? (You may not have the privileges necessary to create a directory; if not your DBA will need to do that for you). Is there a reason you don't want to import the data though?

Comment: Alex, so I'll try to run the "Create Directory" with the privilege required. As soon as I can, I'll post the results. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it's pretty much the first example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_dp_driver.htm#SUTIL1457), just changing the tables names. Of course, that's to unload, not load...

Comment: @glup - you also haven't said how the DMP file you have was created. Is it from an export (legacy or datapump), or from a data-unloading external table - using a command similar to what you showed? As far as I'm aware you can't use a export DMP file for an external table.

Comment: I dont know how the dmp was created. I just recieved the file...probably it was auto generated by the ERP, I guess.

Comment: You probably need to import it then; but you still need to know how it was created really.

Comment: @alex-poole Logged as SYS the commands to CREATE and GRAD permissions worked. But know im getting: ORA-29400: data cartridge error error opening file "C:\ /EMP_XT_2551.log"

Comment: @glup - is the DB server Windows or Linux/UNIX? You used C:\ implying Windows, but path in that error suggests it's really not. You know the directory and file have to be on the DB server, not on your client machine, right?

Comment: @alex-poole You're right. I'm sorry if i'am being too obvious with these questions, but my Toad's client needs to be installed in my Linux server? Or there's a way to keep Toad running on windows server and set the path to Linux's?

Comment: The dump file has to be in a filesystem directory on the Linux, and the Oracle directory object has to point to that. You can create and query the external table from Toad on Windows (or anywhere else, it's just SQL). But again, I think it has to be the right kind of dump file, and it has to be on the server.

Comment: Ok, the files are on Linux's server. But i dont know how to set the path. Do you have any example of query to do that? Like: CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS '\root\backups'; Do I have to declare the IP?

Comment: You set whatever path the files are actually in. I don't know what you mean. And no, the directory is on the Oracle server, it's a local filesystem, so no IP needed.

Comment: Alex, after all, it worked (but backwards lol). Running the code, im getting "Error: The File alread exists". When i change the name of the dump File, in this line: LOCATION ('new.dmp'), a new file is created and I can Select its data. But how can I retrieve data from the original dmp?

Comment: I said in my first comment you don't want the `select as` part. You're using [the example code from the first point in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_dp_driver.htm#SUTIL1457). You need the sixth point. But you have to know what's in the dump file - you have to supply the columns and data types, for a start. I'm still not comvinced it's the right kind of dump file.

Comment: I followed the steps in documentation, as you said, and I got: ORA-29913. Probably its what you've been saying to me from the beginning, unfortunately its not the right kind of dump.I appreciate very much your time and consideration. Thanks.